# Foolbox predicting images and running attacks on images with a saved tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a pre-trained model in Tensorflow (full trained an imagenet pretrained model) with inception_resnet_v2  network architecture. Now, I am using **foolbox** to use **adversarial attacks** on medical images and get the predictions.

But every time the model is **returning a different prediction** (a different class with a different probability) on the original image.Am I reinitializing the weights somehow ?  Moreover, predictions on adversarial images is not working and it's throwing a **NoneType error** every time and I am not able to use any attack.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from nets import nets_factory
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.asarray(Image.open('1.jpg'))
data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, np.float32)
data_tf = tf.reshape(data_tf, [1, 299, 299, 3])
arg_scope = nets_factory.arg_scopes_map['inception_resnet_v2']()

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
(logits, end_points) = \
    nets_factory.networks_map['inception_resnet_v2'](inputs=data_tf, num_classes=2, is_training=False)

with foolbox.models.TensorFlowModel(data_tf, logits, (0, 255)) as model:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    model.session.run(init_op)
    attack = foolbox.attacks.FGSM(model)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
    '/local-scratch/arkadeep/1_June/tf_classification/experiment/final_model/model.ckpt-30589.meta',
    clear_devices=True)
    saver.restore(model.session,
              '/local-scratch/arkadeep/1_June/tf_classification/experiment/final_model/model.ckpt-30589')

    example_label = np.argmax(model.predictions(image))
    print(example_label)
    print(foolbox.utils.softmax(model.predictions(image))[0])

    adversarial = attack(image, example_label, unpack=False)
    print(np.argmax(model.predictions(adversarial.image)))
    print(foolbox.utils.softmax(model.predictions(adversarial))[0])

    print(adversarial.distance)
```

**Here's the stacktrace** :

```
[ada77@cs-mial-ts06 tf_classification]$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python example_code.py 
(1, 299, 299, 3)
2018-06-05 10:53:49.097397: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
0  //the class predicted
0.944639 // probability of the class
/home/ada77/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/foolbox/attacks/base.py:103: UserWarning: GradientSignAttack did not find an adversarial, maybe the model or the criterion is not supported by this attack.
  ' attack.'.format(self.name()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_code.py", line 54, in 
    print(np.argmax(model.predictions(adversarial.image)))
  File "/home/ada77/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/foolbox/models/base.py", line 122, in predictions
    return np.squeeze(self.batch_predictions(image[np.newaxis]), axis=0)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of the rules . Thanks for the caution.

Comment: It isn't really a rule as such - the post at the above link was written because we get so many people wanting priority over other questions, and after several years of it, I am still mystified by the phenomenon. Perhaps you might shed some light on it, just for my curiosity? Is it normal for you to ask volunteers to treat your problem as more important than other people's problems? Do your friends or colleagues do this? I'm not intending to be hostile - I genuinely want to know.

Comment: Nope it is actually urgent. I have a deadline tomorrow, and if I resolve this issue, I am done. So, it was mentioned as urgent.

Comment: Now I am even more confused. You accept that you ought not ask volunteers for preferential treatment, but because you have left something to the last minute, you are asking volunteers for preferential treatment? Moreover, your response doesn't answer my question. I appreciate it is moderately philosophical, and certainly not related to the topic at hand, but I remain curious.